# How send new quantity in state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this code

```
const initialState = {
  asideItems: [],
  total: 0
}

const asideReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_ASIDE:
      const item = action.payload
      const existItem =  state.asideItems.find(item => action.payload.id === item.id)
      if(existItem)
      {
        console.log(item)
        item.quantity += 1
        console.log(item)

        return{
          ...state,
          total: state.total + item.price,
        }
      }
      else{
        return{
          ...state,
          asideItems: [...state.asideItems , item],
          total: state.total + item.price
        }
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I make simple verification, if in `asideItems` exists such item, change its count. For example `item.quantity += 1` working true

```
console.log(item) // Quantity = 1
item.quantity += 1
console.log(item) // Quantity =  2
```

But new quantity don't send in state. What could be causing this?

Comment: you are not updating the state with quantity

Comment: You don't return `quantity` - I don't see what you expect to happen.

Comment: @BiswaBhusan but  how update the state with quantity to this item?

Comment: can you tell me how does tour payload looks like in action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted several issues here.
First, the switch statement isn't syntactically valid. ADD_TO_ASIDE needs to be quoted.
Second, you're not using a functional approach to update your items quantity, instead you're mutating the variable in-place, it won't work this way with redux. Check out [the rules of reducers](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#rules-of-reducers).

```js
const asideReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_ASIDE":
      const updatedAsideItems = state.asideItems.map(currentItem => {
        if (currentItem.id === action.payload.id) {
          return {...currentItem, quantity: (currentItem.quantity || 0) + 1}
        } else {
          return currentItem
        }
      })
      
      return { ...state, asideItems: updatedAsideItems, total: state.total + action.payload.price}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-fog-hpsbc?file=/src/index.js)

---